# How to join separate shapes in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, shapes

Ok, so this might seem a simple enough task to anyone, but I'm really struggling.

I have 50-60 of these patterns. All made up from a number of paths (these are not joined in anyway and have gaps in between them at some points.

I basically need my end result to be one complete outline of the shape which I can fill in with a colour, the end result being something like this:

What's the easiest way to achieve this?

My first attempt took my almost 20 minutes, 
I had to first join the paths where they meet 1by1 (Nightmare)
Then removing the paths from insdie the shape one by one (Nightmare)
Then creating a compound path
Filling in the shape with a colour black

[image]

[image]

This is what happens when I try the Ctrl + J to join just the outside paths:

[image]

I have used Join tool, but this is a huge task as there is probably 40-50 gaps between the paths. im trying to avoid this...

Comment: Do you use the "Join tool" to stitch the paths?

Comment: When trying to use Command/Ctrl-J.. make certain the paths are part of any group.. and that you have the *entire* path selected (no "hollow" white anchors.. all solid square anchors). It *should* work given these two things.

Answer (score 1):

- Select all the outer path of a shape and press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> +
  <kbd>J</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> Win to join the
  points.
- Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to invert stroke color/fill color to diferenciate it from the open paths.
- When all the shapes are done, use the **Magic Wand Tool** to select all the paths with just stroke color and delete them.

[image]

Comment: Hi Daniello, thanks but I seem to have this problem when I try that ill update post above!.